# FontAwesome SCSS Tree-Shaking

Tags: reactjs, sass, font-awesome, font-awesome-5, tree-shaking

using the method described at https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/sass I believe I will end up accumulating almost 2.8MB of web fonts in the `src` folder of my React project. I need to use CSS to add icons to a calendar style, but won't that affect tree shaking? In other words, won't I end up with a huge package size just for using a single icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method @Mike Poole presented is the most correct one for tree shaking. If you use the webfont method, you have no option but to load the entire set. But if you need to use just a few icons, and can't load 'em via js for some reason, you can simply get the svg files you need and add them directly, as either `<img>` tags or background-images.

Answer (score 0):

Tree shaking using FontAwesome is straightforwards. If you only use a single icon then you only need to import that icon (and certainly don't need to use SASS to do so).

Here is the example that FontAwesome use if you only want to use the solid `fa-coffee` icon:

```
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
```

Comment: Thank you. But in my case, I need to use CSS and so cannot use this method.